# How to merge these two queries into 1 to meet the condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a lot of difficulty trying to implement this particular query as a relative mild beginner with mysql and syntax.

I have 3 tables

- SYMBOLS_LIST (contains a list of stock symbols)  (key=SYMBOL)
- T50DMA    (contains the 50 Day Moving Average already calculated for each symbol each
  day)    (contains DATE, FIFTY_DAY_MA columns)
- T200DMA (contains the 200 Day    Moving Average already calculated for each symbol each
  day) (contains DATE,    TWO_HUNDRED_DAY_MA columns)

I am trying to determine a list of symbols in which the 50DMA price has crossover the 200DMA price for today's date.  The moving averages have already been calculated and stored in the respective table, so a moving average calculation is not needed.

To detect the crossover, I am trying to implement the following to get a list of symbols where:

```
Today's 50DMA t1 > Today's 200DMA t2
  AND
Yesterday's 50DMA t1 <= Yesterday's 200DMA t2
```

The most that I have been able to write is a two separate queries that give me a list of the first and the second, but I am unsure how to combine them to meet the condition written above.

How can this be written to meet both conditions in 1 statement? Thank you very much for any assistance  you can offer.

Additional Edit:

Here are the two queries I was able to construct:

```
**Today's 50DMA t1 > Today's 200DMA t2**

select t1.SYMBOL from T50DMA t1, T200DMA t2 where 
t1.SYMBOL IN (SELECT SYMBOL from SYMBOLS_LIST) AND 
t1.SYMBOL=t2.SYMBOL AND
(t1.DATE='2015-12-10' AND t2.DATE='2015-12-10' AND 
t1.FIFTY_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE > t2.TWO_HUNDRED_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE) GROUP BY      
t1.SYMBOL, t1.DATE;

**Yesterday's 50DMA t1 <= Yesterday's 200DMA t2**

select t1.SYMBOL from T50DMA t1, T200DMA t2 where   
t1.SYMBOL IN (SELECT SYMBOL from SYMBOLS_LIST) AND   
t1.SYMBOL=t2.SYMBOL AND    
(t1.DATE='2015-12-10' - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND t2.DATE='2015-12-10' - INTERVAL 1   
DAY AND 
t1.FIFTY_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE <= t2.TWO_HUNDRED_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE) GROUP BY  
t1.SYMBOL, t1.DATE;
```

I am just not sure how to combine these to make both conditions valid in 1 statement to have only those symbols that meet the conditions be returned.  Thanks for your help with this.

12/14/2015 Edit:
I tried this query, but it return no results at all.  If I comment out either line and run it, I get the results for one or the other query, but nothing when both are defined.  What is wrong with the query?  I am stuck.

```
select t1.SYMBOL 
from T50DMA t1, T200DMA t2 
where t1.SYMBOL IN (SELECT SYMBOL from SYMBOLS_LIST) 
AND ((t1.SYMBOL=t2.SYMBOL) AND (t1.DATE='2015-12-10' AND t2.DATE='2015-12-10') AND (t1.FIFTY_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE > t2.TWO_HUNDRED_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE))
AND ((t1.SYMBOL=t2.SYMBOL) AND (t1.DATE='2015-12-09' AND t2.DATE='2015-12-09') AND (t1.FIFTY_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE <= t2.TWO_HUNDRED_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE));
```

**In Response to Dijkgraaf:**

Assuming that condition 1 for today's 50 DMA > today's 200 DMA  (AND) Yesterday's 50 DMA <= Yesterday's 200 DMA, I would expect to see just a list of symbols (or with today's date) indicating that the crossover occurred such as:

```
'2015-12-14 00:00:00', 'AAON'
'2015-12-14 00:00:00', 'ADGE'
'2015-12-14 00:00:00', 'BLK'
'2015-12-14 00:00:00', 'CRY'
```

I took data from yesterday (2015-12-14) and compared to the previous trade day (2015-12-11) by checking the data in Excel by doing an

```
 AND(IF(today's 50DMA>Today's 200 DMA,1,0),IF(Yesterday's 50 DMA<=Yesterday's 200DMA,1,0))  1=True, 0=False

Here are a few entries of data:
TODAY'S DATE    SYMBOL  50DMA   200DMA      YESTERDAY DATE  SYMBOL  50DMA     200DMA        RESULT
12/14/2015 0:00 ADGE    0.4991  0.498       12/11/2015 0:00 ADGE    0.4958  0.4979      TRUE
12/14/2015 0:00 CRY     10.432  10.429      12/11/2015 0:00 CRY     10.426  10.429      TRUE

For ADGE, it would be:
(0.4991 > 0.498) AND (0.4958 <= 0.4979) = true 50 DMA crossed over 200 DMA
For CRY, it would be:
(10.432 > 10.429) AND (10.426 <= 10.429) = true 50 DMA crossed over 200 DMA
```

For some reason, I don't understand why the query won't return back with any symbols. I may have not implemented it correctly or I am confusing it on the dates somehow?

```
select t1.SYMBOL 
from T50DMA t1, T200DMA t2 
where t1.SYMBOL IN (SELECT SYMBOL from SYMBOLS_LIST) 
AND ((t1.SYMBOL=t2.SYMBOL) AND (t1.DATE='2015-12-14' AND t2.DATE='2015-12-14') AND (t1.FIFTY_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE > t2.TWO_HUNDRED_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE))
AND ((t1.SYMBOL=t2.SYMBOL) AND (t1.DATE='2015-12-11' AND t2.DATE='2015-12-11') AND (t1.FIFTY_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE <= t2.TWO_HUNDRED_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE));
```

**Additional Question (2015-03-17):**

On a side question, is there a way to determine (by case or if statement) that if the Interval - 1 day falls on a Sunday or Saturday to have it pick that previous Friday?  In some cases, even for a Friday (like Good Friday) the market would be closed in which no data would be produced.  I do have a lookup table for each week (start date and end date) of the actual market date range for each week in a table called "WEEKLY_LOOKUP".  For instance, if on a Friday the market is closed, the table would indicate the End Date would be for a "Thursday" instead of a Friday.

To handle two cases:
1) If Interval - 1 day is on a Saturday or Sunday, then the next business day is Friday.
2) But if Friday is a non-market day, it would need to be set for the previous Thursday.  Is there a way to reference the WEEKLY_LOOKUP (END DATE) in the table?  For instance, Friday 2015-03-25 the market is closed.

```
            WEEKLY_LOOKUP
START_DATE             END_DATE
'2016-03-21 00:00:00', '2016-03-24 00:00:00'
```

Then this would produce for example a Current Day of 2016-03-28 and a previous day to compare to of 2016-03-24.

Is there a way to implement into the the same query or would it make it too complex to handle?  Thank you!!

Comment: So do you want the symbols that appear in both selects?  Give some sample data and what you expect the outcome to be to illustrate your question.

Comment: Hi Dijkgraff, I provided a response with additional information. thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Thank you Dijkgraaf!! I will validate this against closing day results and let you know the outcome! I did run this against previous days in which the queries you have constructed worked in providing a list of symbols.  Based upon the examples above for 2015-12-14, I did see them appear in the list.  I will provide confirmation later this evening once I get new data in and am able to compare against another source.  Certainly, I was completely off with my initial query and would have no way been able to solution this without your generosity and expertise! Thank you Sir! Will write more later.

Comment: I was able to confirm against the data, this works great!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say AND in SQL it means, it must match both conditions. 
You have both `t1.DATE='2015-12-10'` and `t1.DATE='2015-12-09'` as those can't be true at the same time you get no results.

Even though the data is coming from the same table, you need to treat them as separate tables by using an alias.

However, first for ease of reading the SQL, lets reformat your SQL using Joins, rather than complex WHERE clauses and also giving the second query different aliases

```
**Today's 50DMA t1 > Today's 200DMA t2**

select t1.SYMBOL 
from T50DMA t1
INNER JOIN T200DMA t2 ON t2.SYMBOL=t1.SYMBOL
where t1.SYMBOL IN (SELECT SYMBOL from SYMBOLS_LIST) 
AND t1.DATE='2015-12-10' AND t2.DATE='2015-12-10' 
AND t1.FIFTY_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE > t2.TWO_HUNDRED_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE
GROUP BY  t1.SYMBOL, t1.DATE;

**Yesterday's 50DMA t1 <= Yesterday's 200DMA t2**

select t3.SYMBOL 
from T50DMA t3
INNER JOIN T200DMA t4 ON t4.SYMBOL=t3.SYMBOL
where t3.SYMBOL IN (SELECT SYMBOL from SYMBOLS_LIST)
AND  t3.DATE='2015-12-10' - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND t4.DATE='2015-12-10' - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
AND t3.FIFTY_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE <= t4.TWO_HUNDRED_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE
GROUP BY t3.SYMBOL, t3.DATE;
```

Now to add them together.

```
select t1.SYMBOL 
from T50DMA t1
INNER JOIN T200DMA t2 ON t2.SYMBOL=t1.SYMBOL
INNER JOIN T50DMA t3 ON t3.SYMBOL=t1.SYMBOL
INNER JOIN T200DMA t4 ON t4.SYMBOL=t3.SYMBOL  
where t1.SYMBOL IN (SELECT SYMBOL from SYMBOLS_LIST) 
AND t1.DATE='2015-12-10' 
AND t2.DATE='2015-12-10' 
AND t3.DATE='2015-12-10' - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
AND t4.DATE='2015-12-10' - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND t1.FIFTY_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE > t2.TWO_HUNDRED_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE
AND t3.FIFTY_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE <= t4.TWO_HUNDRED_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE
GROUP BY  t1.SYMBOL, t1.DATE;
```

And then simplify it a bit more

```
select t1.SYMBOL 
from T50DMA t1
INNER JOIN T200DMA t2 ON t2.SYMBOL=t1.SYMBOL AND t2.DATE=t1.DATE
INNER JOIN T50DMA t3 ON t3.SYMBOL=t1.SYMBOL AND t3.DATE=t1.DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
INNER JOIN T200DMA t4 ON t4.SYMBOL=t1.SYMBOL AND t4.DATE=t3.DATE
where t1.SYMBOL IN (SELECT SYMBOL from SYMBOLS_LIST) 
AND t1.DATE='2015-12-10'             
AND t1.FIFTY_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE > t2.TWO_HUNDRED_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE 
AND t3.FIFTY_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE <= t4.TWO_HUNDRED_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE
GROUP BY t1.SYMBOL, t1.DATE
```

Hopefully I haven't munged any of your queries.  Try that an see if you get what you expect.

P.S. Note sure why you are grouping on DATE as you are only selecting a single date, but possibly you meant to do this and not select a single date.

```
select t1.SYMBOL, t1.DATE
from T50DMA t1
INNER JOIN T200DMA t2 ON t2.SYMBOL=t1.SYMBOL AND t2.DATE=t1.DATE
INNER JOIN T50DMA t3 ON t3.SYMBOL=t1.SYMBOL AND t3.DATE=t1.DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
INNER JOIN T200DMA t4 ON t4.SYMBOL=t1.SYMBOL AND t4.DATE=t3.DATE
where t1.SYMBOL IN (SELECT SYMBOL from SYMBOLS_LIST) 
AND t1.FIFTY_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE > t2.TWO_HUNDRED_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE 
AND t3.FIFTY_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE <= t4.TWO_HUNDRED_DAY_MOVING_AVERAGE
GROUP BY t1.SYMBOL, t1.DATE
```